# Linear Algebra Explanation required

Tags: linear-algebra

Having trouble understanding this problem and looking for some explanation of the answer that was provided in my notes. I need to give a linear transformation $T: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ such that 
$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1
\\1   
\end{bmatrix}\right)
= 
3$ and $T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
-1
\\2   
\end{bmatrix}\right)
= 
6$ an find a matrix $A$ such that $T=T_A$, i.ie., $T$ is a left multiplication of A.

The solution:

for $T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\y  
\end{bmatrix}\right)
$ in $R^2$, $\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\y   
\end{bmatrix}\right)
= 
1/3(2x+y)$ $\left[\begin{array}{cc} 
1
\\1
\end{array}\right]+ (y-x)/3\left[\begin{array}{cc} 
1
\\2
\end{array}\right]  $ the solution goes on from here and I can understand the rest, but I am getting tripped up in this first step. Just looking for some clarification of what is happening in this step. Where does $1/3(2x+y)$ and $(y-x)/3$ come from?

Comment: You need to understand how $T$ acts on the basis vectors. In your case you should use the standard basis $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: Solve the two equations $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \alpha\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+\beta\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \gamma\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+\delta\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$, or more simply, $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix} = u\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+v\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Nicolas FRANCOIS but how did he get 1/3(2x+y) I can not figure that out

Comment: Is $T(-1,2)=6$ or $T(1,2)=6?$

Comment: Solve the system !

Comment: @mfl (-1,2) = 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linear map $T: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ is of the form $T(x,y)=ax+by.$ You want to have $T(1,1)=3$ and $T(-1,2)=6.$ Since $T(1,1)=a+b$ and $T(-1,2)=-a+2b$ you need to solve the system

$$\begin{align}a+b&=2\\-a+2b&=6\end{align}$$ and you are done.

Note that $$(a,b)\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=ax+by.$$ So the matrix you are looking for is just $(a,b).$

**Edit**

Note that $$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\dfrac{2x+y}{3}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\dfrac{y-x}{3}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\end{pmatrix}.$$ It comes from

$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\dfrac{2}{3}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\dfrac{-1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\end{pmatrix}$$ and

$$\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\dfrac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\dfrac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\end{pmatrix}.$$ Now

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=x\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$ and you will get the answer using the equalities above. How? Note that

\begin{align}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} &\\ &= x\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\\ &=x\left[\dfrac{2}{3}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\dfrac{-1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\end{pmatrix}\right]+y\left[\dfrac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\dfrac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\end{pmatrix}\right]\\ &=\dfrac{2x}{3}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\dfrac{-x}{3}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\end{pmatrix}+\dfrac{y}{3}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\dfrac{y}{3}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\end{pmatrix}\\ &=\dfrac{2x+y}{3}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\dfrac{y-x}{3}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\end{pmatrix}.\end{align}

Comment: but how did he get 1/3(2x+y) for the first one, I am trying to follow his prodecude

Comment: I have editted the answer. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I understand this part $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\dfrac{2}{3}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\dfrac{-1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\end{pmatrix}$$ and

$$\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\dfrac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\dfrac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\end{pmatrix}.$$ but the now... you will get the answer using the equalities above part is still a bit confusing, could you clarify that? thanks so much for your time

Comment: thanks so much for that final edit I understand it now, one last question. when all that is worked out it boils down to 3y = the matrix (0,3) in this problem I assume y = the matrix (0,1) so 3y would be = (3x0,3x1)?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand well what you are asking. If you mean that the vector $(0,3)$ is equal to $3(0,1)$ you're right.

Comment: @ mfl yeah that's what I mean, thank you very much for your time you have clarified everything quite well

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is
$$
\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since the matrix associated to the linear map with respect to the given basis on the domain and the canonical basis on the codomain is
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}
$$
the matrix associated to it with respect to the canonical basis on the domain is
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}^{\!-1}=
\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}
$$